# Can behavior of `W` be changed by modifying syntax entries?

Tags: evil

I want `dW` and `dB` to not delete brackets in racket (all 3 kinds `[`, `(`, `{`).

I'm looking at changing `W` and not `w` because `w` is still useful for changing parts of an identifier, e.g. I can easily change `any-of-these-dash-separated-parts` individually.

There is no explicit entry for `W` in documentation https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable

So I'm left wondering how I might modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: `evil-maps.el` defines inner and outer text objects, `dW` and `dB` corresponding to the following outer ones:

```
(define-key evil-outer-text-objects-map "W" 'evil-a-WORD)
(define-key evil-outer-text-objects-map "B" 'evil-a-curly)
```

Their definition in `evil-commands.el`:

```
(evil-define-text-object evil-a-WORD (count &optional beg end type)
  "Select a WORD."
  (evil-select-an-object 'evil-WORD beg end type count))

(evil-define-text-object evil-a-curly (count &optional beg end type)
  "Select a curly bracket (\"brace\")."
  :extend-selection nil
  (evil-select-paren ?{ ?} beg end type count t))
```

You'll have to define your own text objects instead.  The API for that is that a text object is expected to be a range of start and end position.  `evil-select-an-object` is the most generic way of doing this, it repurposes the `thingatpt.el` API for which defines objects in terms of forward (and optionally backward) movement.  This means that all that's necessary to use `evil-WORD` as argument, is to define `forward-evil-WORD`.  Look at its definition to get an idea how simple it is to define a custom version of that:

```
(defun forward-evil-WORD (&optional count)
  "[...]"
  (evil-forward-nearest count
                        #'(lambda (&optional cnt)
                            (evil-forward-chars "^\n\r\t\f " cnt))
                        #'forward-evil-empty-line))
```

Chances are you only need to adjust the charset passed to `evil-forward-chars`.

For the other text object, tricky, you'd most certainly be better off defining text objects for symbols and s-expressions.  This has been done before: https://github.com/luxbock/evil-cleverparens